# What's the equivalent jade code for this ejs code?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, syntax, pug

In ejs you can do something like this.

```
<ul id="photos" class="photos">
  <% req.photos.forEach(function(photo) { %>
    <li style="background-image: url(<%= photo.picture %>>);" class="<%= photo.link %>">
      <a href="<%= photo.link %>>" target="_top"></a>
    </li>
  <% }); %>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to do something that is just like this, but I can't get it to work. What's particularly confusing is how to make loops work and what to escape and how to escape it.

What would this code look like in Jade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be:

```
ul(id='photos',class='photos')
  - req.photos.forEach(function(photo){
    li(style='background-image: url('+photo.picture+');', class=photo.link)
      a(href=photo.link, target='_top')
  - })
```

basically you need to escape strings only when using them inside attributes

see https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/#code & https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/#attributes for more info.

Comment: not sure why you're using javascript when you can just use `for photo in photos` without the leading `-`s